# Terminal switch tabs not working Yosemite

Tags: terminal, macos, system-settings

I had added keyboard shortcuts and those were working pretty fine on OSX Mavericks but not working in Yosemite. On pressing shortcut for switching tab terminal just flashes. Check screen shot of my settings
I want my shortcuts working on Yosemite like those were working on Mavericks
[image]

Comment: So what’s your question?

Comment: I want shortcuts working on yosemite like those were working on Mavericks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to modify the menu title to enter the exact name of the menu command you want to add.

[image]

Comment: can we change these shortcuts through command line ÷

Comment: Could someone add an example of what an exact command name looks like, e.g. for "I want to press Play on the Commands menu in iTunes"? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The menu option `Select Previous Tab` is changed to `Show Previous Tab` and there is by default key shortcut for it

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>}</kbd>  Show Next Tab

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>{</kbd>  Show Previous Tab